# PHP Do not convert between 2 tags

Tags: php

I have a string. With "pre" tag inside. I don't want to replace the texts in this pre tag. How can I do that?

```
<?php
$str="
<b>test</b>
<pre>
<b>test</b>
</pre>
<b>test</b>
";
function htmltobb($str){
    $str=preg_replace('(<b>)','[b]',$str);
    $str=preg_replace('(</b>)','[/b]',$str);
    return $str;
}
echo htmltobb($str);
?>
```

result:

```
[b]test[/b]
<pre>
[b]test[/b]
</pre>
[b]test[/b]
```

what i want?

```
[b]test[/b]
<pre>
<b>test</b> <-- this line not replaced
</pre>
[b]test[/b]
```

thank you for all answers

Comment: Be cool to see if someone can Regex that :)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1064767

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A messy approach could be taking everything between `pre` tags, HTML encoding it, parse everything else, then decode the entities back to characters... this assumes regexs are required and you already have read about their [pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3783243).

```
$str="
<b>test</b>
<pre>
<b>test</b>
</pre>
<b>test</b>
";
echo preg_replace_callback(htmlspecialchars('~(?s)<pre>.*?</pre>~'), function($match) { return htmlspecialchars_decode($match[0]);}, preg_replace('~<(/?)b>~','[$1b]', preg_replace_callback('~(?s)<pre>.*?</pre>~', function($match) { return htmlspecialchars($match[0]);}, $str)));
```

https://3v4l.org/UZbc2

Start with:

```
<b>test</b>
<pre>
<b>test</b>
</pre>
<b>test</b>
```

First run converts to:

```
<b>test</b>
&lt;pre&gt;
&lt;b&gt;test&lt;/b&gt;
&lt;/pre&gt;
<b>test</b>
```

Second converts to:

```
[b]test[/b]
&lt;pre&gt;
&lt;b&gt;test&lt;/b&gt;
&lt;/pre&gt;
[b]test[/b]
```

Third puts it back as intended:

```
[b]test[/b]
<pre>
<b>test</b>
</pre>
[b]test[/b]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to go cutting your string, do the replace when not inside a pre, and not when yes inside a pre.

```
$str="
<b>test</b>
<pre>
<b>test</b>
</pre>
<b>test</b>
";

echo htmltobb($str);

function htmltobb($str){    
    $aux = '';
    $posB = 0;
    while (($posA = mb_strpos($str, '<pre>', $posB)) !== false) {
        $aux .= preg_replace(['(<b>)', '(</b>)'], ['[b]', '[/b]'], mb_substr($str, 0, $posA));
        $posB = mb_strpos($str, '</pre>', $posA);
        $aux .= mb_substr($str, $posA, $posB - $posA);
    }
    $aux .= preg_replace(['(<b>)', '(</b>)'], ['[b]', '[/b]'], mb_substr($str, $posB));

    return $aux;
}
```